# Pay pal Java api - Payment by credit card - Singapore (CURRENCY_NOT_ALLOWED)

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I am using paypal java api for credit card payment with SGD but i am getting the below error.

**Error code : 400 with response :** {"name":"CURRENCY_NOT_ALLOWED","message":"Currency is not supported","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#CURRENCY_NOT_ALLOWED","debug_id":"d5473b485675e"}

**My sample Request is**

```
{
  "intent": "sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "credit_card",
    "funding_instruments": [
      {
        "credit_card": {
          "number": "1111111111111111",
          "type": "mastercard",
          "expire_month": 11,
          "expire_year": 2018,
          "cvv2": 111,
          "first_name": "Joe",
          "last_name": "Shopper",
          "billing_address": {
            "line1": "52 N Main ST",
            "city": "Singapore",
            "country_code": "SG",
            "postal_code": "120210"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "transactions": [
    {
      "amount": {
        "currency": "SGD",
        "total": "7",
        "details": {
          "shipping": "1",
          "subtotal": "5",
          "tax": "1"
        }
      },
      "description": "This is the payment transaction description."
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SGD` is not supported for Direct Credit Card Payments.

Supported Currencies: `USD, GBP,CAD,EUR and JPY`

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest_api_payment_country_currency_support/

The only option for Singapore merchants to accept direct credit card is to use [Hosted Sole Solution](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/website-payments-pro-hosted-solution/)

Comment: Thanks will look for other alternatives

Comment: you can look at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/website-payments-pro-hosted-solution/